# Why isn't arr[0] (var = first) getting compared to arr[i] (the counter variable) explicitly? What is getting compared here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Several parts to my question: Assuming I have matching numbers in my function arguments, why does this code output true no matter what the number in the for loop counter, for example:

```
(var i = 54321; i < arr.length; i++)
```

Is set as? Also, I can put any number in the `var first = arr[0]` assignment, for example, `first = arr[12345];` and the output will still be true.  I thought `arr[0]`  was getting compared against `arr[i]`, so the counter needed to be `0` or `1`.

It appears I can put any numbers in the counter *and* the first array and the output will always be true.  Why is this?  What is actually going on here?

```
function isUniform(arr){
    var first = arr[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] !== first) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

isUniform(2,2,2,2);  // any series of all matching numbers will output true.
```

Those are among the questions I have.  Any answers are greatly appreciated.  Also, this is my first question, and a rather rookie one at that.  Feel free to let me know what I'm doing wrong on the forum here, if anything, and any edits I or anyone need(s) to make.  Thanks.

Comment: you pass the argument in wrong way. try this " isUniform([2,3,4]) "

Comment: Your function expects an array, not multiple arguments.

Comment: FYI: in es6 you could do ... `function isUniform(...arr)` - and the rest of the code needs no change

Comment: My bad if I wasn't clear enough.  I want the output to be true, but why can I switch the first array and the counter to any numbers and it still outputs true?  Doesn't arr[0] have to be set to 0 (for the first item in the array) and the counter have to be set to 1?  Obviously not, why is that?  Why can I put any numbers in either spot.  I thought I had to compare the first array, arr[0], with the first item in the for loop.  Again, rookie question.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @dannymac: Your code for `isUniform` is correct and does work. Or: would work if `arr` was an array like `[2, 2, 2, 2]`. But it's not, it's just the number `2` in your call!

Comment: @Bergi, yeah I was aware of that.  I was wondering why it worked no matter what numbers I gave to my variable 'first' as well as the counter.  My post got edited quite a bit as well (and rightfully so).  Will try to do better on my formatting and my clarity in the future.  Kind of hard when you're not sure how to ask what you're trying to ask haha.  Obviously, I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being bitten by undefined.
Let's dig a bit deeper.

```
function isUniform(arr){
    var first = arr[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] !== first) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

isUniform(2,2,2,2);  // any series of all matching numbers will output true.
```

You are passing 4 arguments, but reading just one (JavaScript doesn't complain), and calling it arr. So, in your example, arr == 2.
Being equal to 2, arr[0] yields undefined. arr.length is undefined, too.
So the for loop exits and you always get true. You should use the special `arguments` parameter:

```
function isUniform(){
    var first = arguments[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        if(arguments[i] !== first) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

isUniform(2,2,2,2);  // yields true
isUniform(2,3,2,2);  // yields false
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for a reference:

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for.  Was wondering why I could pass in any numbers to both the loop and my first variable and it would still always output true.  I will read up and keep practicing. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer responds to your question, you should flag it as accepted ;).

Comment: Checking how to do that right now.  I upvoted but little rep yet.  I'll look into it.  Thanks.